# How to concat CameraUpdate animations

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I want to run a `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds` animation, the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory#newLatLngBounds(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds,%20int)) state that:

> Returns a CameraUpdate that transforms the camera such that the
>   specified latitude/longitude bounds are **centered on screen** within a
>   bounding box of specified dimensions at the greatest possible zoom
>   level. You can specify additional padding, to further restrict the
>   size of the bounding box. The returned CameraUpdate has a bearing of 0
>   and a tilt of 0.

But I don't want it to be centered on screen, I want to shift up the focus area, imagine an *"align_parent_top"*. So I have a `CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy` to achieve it.

```
CameraUpdate move = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(
            builder.build(), 
            getUtils().getScreenAbsoluteWith(), 
            mAvailableHeight,
            mDefaultMapPadding);

CameraUpdate scroll = CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(0,mAvailableHeight + mDefaultMapPadding));
```

And then:

```
mMap.animateCamera(move, new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mMap.animateCamera(scroll);

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
});
```

Unfortunately what I really wanted was to run both animations together. Or, somehow, create a `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds` which wouldn't be centered on screen.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem to calculate `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds` which wouldn't be centered on screen?

Comment: How can i "add" a scrollBy pixel value to a LatLngBounds?

Comment: Just convert Lat/Lng bounds  to screen pixels, then add pixels, then convert pixels to Lat\Lng back...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, didn't know I had something like this: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection

Going to try it.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert Lat/Lng bounds to screen pixels, then add pixels, then convert pixels to Lat\Lng back:

```
...
private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
...

// convert LatLng bounds to screen coords
Point pointNortheast = projection.toScreenLocation(latLngBounds.northeast);
Point pointSouthwest = projection.toScreenLocation(latLngBounds.southwest);

// modify bounds in screen coords
pointNortheast.y += scrollByPixel;
pointSouthwest.y += scrollByPixel;

// convert screen coords back to LatLng
LatLng geoNortheast = projection.fromScreenLocation(pointNortheast);
LatLng geoSouthwest = projection.fromScreenLocation(pointSouthwest);
LatLngBounds modifiedBounds = new LatLngBounds(geoSouthwest, geoNortheast);

// animate camera to new bounds
mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(modifiedBounds, 0));
...
```